# Back button press immediately closes Capacitor app on Android

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework, capacitor

I am using Capacitor to build an Android app from my Angular web app and I would like to connect the native back button press event with the `window.history.back()` such that it does not close the app and instead go back in the window history.

So I added a listener on the backButton event, but it does not get triggered at all, the app just closes immediately.

This is my code for registering the listener:

```js
import { App } from '@capacitor/app';

export function registerAndroidBackSwipe() {
    App.addListener('backButton', (event) => {
        console.warn(event); // <-- does not even log!
        if (event.canGoBack) {
            window.history.back();
        } else {
            App.exitApp().catch(e => console.error(e));
        }
    });

    return true;
}
```

and I wrap it in a provider function for my standalone Angular app like this:

```js
export function provideAndroidBackSwipe() {
    return makeEnvironmentProviders([
        {
            provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
            multi: true,
            useFactory:  () => {
                return Capacitor.getPlatform() === 'android'
                    ? registerAndroidBackSwipe
                    : () => false;
            },
        },
    ]);
}
```

MainActivity:

```java
import com.getcapacitor.BridgeActivity;

public class MainActivity extends BridgeActivity {}
```

I did a build of the Angular web app, then `npx cap sync`, opened Android Studio, did `Sync Project with Gradle Files`, but this does not help. I tried all solutions I found online but I could not resolve it with the provided solutions on Stackoverflow and other forums.

I debugged it and the registerAndroidBackSwipe function gets invoked, but the callback in the listener is not called at all, probably because the default behavior is not overwritten somehow, such that the app closes before the callback would be invoked.

Note, that I am not using Ionic - only Capacitor and Angular.

Comment: Do you have a log showing any stacktrace/errors? https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/logcat

Comment: I don't have any error logs

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using
`App.addListener('backButton', (event) => {`

Use get the canGoBack response directly as below:

```
export function registerAndroidBackSwipe() {
App.addListener('backButton', ({canGoBack}) => {
    if (canGoBack) {
        window.history.back();
    } else {
        App.exitApp().catch(e => console.error(e));
    }
});

return true;
```

}